# ASP.NET MVC ViewResult vs PartialViewResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between the controller result named `ViewResult` and `PartialViewResult`? More importantly, when is the `PartialViewResult` used?

Answer (score 56):

PartialViewResult is used to render a partialview (fx. just a user control). This is pretty nifty for AJAX stuff, i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get(
        "/MyController/MyAction",
        null,
        function (data) { $("#target").html(data) }
     );
</script>
```

and action

```
public ActionResult MyAction() 
{
    return PartialView("SomeView");
}
```

where SomeView is a MVC User Control, e.g.:

```
<div>
   <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
</div>
```

Comment: But why is it needed?  You can just as easily return a usercontrol with a regular View("SomeView")?

Comment: I'd say: mostly semantics. if you check Codeplex source you'll they both inherit from ViewResultBase and the main difference is ViewResult supports specifying master page, PartialViewResult doesn't

Comment: The important point is the one about the master page. When using PartialViewResult you usually want to return just a chunk of markup, not a whole page with DOCTYPE, <html> tag, script references and so on. It's very useful in Ajax scenarios.

Comment: it's handy when you have a user control that you don't want to be coupled to any given page. In my current problem, I have a user control in a master. I don't want every page to get it's data source so I need the control to go and get it's data. I suspect that what this action is for..

Answer (score 30):

http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2008/09/16/the-mvc-platform-action-result-views.aspx

> In practice, you’ll use the
>   PartialViewResult for outputing  a
>   small part of a view. That’s why you
>   don’t have the master page options
>   when dealing with them. On the other
>   hand, you’ll use the ViewResult for
>   getting a “complete” view. As you
>   might expect, the Controller class
>   exposes several methods that will let
>   you reduce the ammount of typing
>   needed for instanting these types of
>   action results.

Generally speaking, ViewResult is for rendering a page with optional master, and PartialViewResult is used for user controls (likely responding to an AJAX request).

Answer (score 23):

none of the existing answers actually answer the question "What is the difference".

The differences are as follows:

1) the locations where the view engine will attempt to find the view:

- for ViewResult, it's in ViewLocationFormats and MasterLocationFormats
- for PartialViewResult, it's in PartialViewLocationFormats

2) ViewResult has the additional property MasterName

that is all.

Comment: It is interesting that you answered this after 5 years and I added one more up-vote after 2 years.

Answer (score 7):

There are several cases where you would want to break down your view into several small components.  One use case that I am working with right now, is I have a multi-lingual site that I would like to reload content using AJAX principles.

Normally what I would do in the case of a non-multi lingual site is to create another ActionResult to return the ViewModel that is changing with the new parameters.  I like to use a custom ActionResult that I have called JsonpResult.  The problem resides in the fact that I have labels not in my database but in Resource files.  So what I would need to do is to somehow hydrate my Resource file data into the ViewModel.

Once the data comes down the pipe, my AJAX callback handles the wiring up of the ViewModel response back to the HTML page using Javascript (I use jQuery).

This definitely works, however it becomes a question of maintainability.  I now need to not only maintain my original ASP.NET view, but I also need to maintain a set of scripts that handle AJAXian behavior.  If you need to have your site SEO, then you really need to make sure that both the Server Side and Client Side behavior are both working the same.

This is where Partial Views come into play for me.  What I do is "pull out" the logical data sections where the bulk of the reload occurs.  The nice thing about PartialView is that you can pass your ViewData and Model along to the PartialView.  If your PartialView is strongly typed against your ViewModel you can get Intellisense to help with the wiring of the PartialView.

Now all I need to do with my AJAX call is to write the response back to a single DIV rather than handling data points individually.  What it does mean is that there would be more content coming down the pipe.  However, the trade off is easier to read and maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

The one of the main differences is PartialViewResult doesn't use _ViewStart.cshtml. The code from _ViewStart.cshtml file executes at the start of rendering before any code in the view.